# What is causing this while function to terminate?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to make code where a pointer variable is assigned to an array index. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int iChoice;
    int *iArray[4];
    int iNumber;
    *iArray = iNumber;

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        iArray[x] = '\0';
    }

    do {
        system("clear");
        printf("\n\t\tENTER NUMBERS INTO AN ARRAY\n");
        printf("\nArray element #1: %d", iArray[0]);
        printf("\nArray element #2: %d", iArray[1]);
        printf("\nArray element #3: %d", iArray[2]);
        printf("\nArray element #4: %d", iArray[3]);
        printf("\nArray element #5: %d", iArray[4]);
        printf("\n\nEnter an array number to access: ");
        scanf("%d", &iChoice);
    } while (iChoice = NULL);

    do {
        printf("\n\t\tEnter a number to fill in: ");
        scanf("%d", &iNumber);
        break;
    } while (iChoice != NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the program, it terminates where I enter an array number to access. Is this because you can't change the value of iChoice with a `scanf` function? I must admit, `iChoice` is not initialized at all except for user input values.

Before I rewrote my program, I tried to use a `while` loop in place of the current `do while` and an `if` statement where the current `while` is. I thought that it would shift program control correctly, but apparently you need booleans or something in the `if`. That didn't work.

Comment: Having `iChoice = NULL` when it should be `iChoice == NULL`?

Comment: I actually tried that just before you told me, this enables me to change the array element's value but after that's done, code terminates.

Comment: ok, will update.

Comment: What's `iArray`?  Where does it point?  It's strange to set `*iArray = iNumber;`, then turn around and set `iArray[0]` (and `iArray[1]`, `iArray[2]`, ...) to `'\0'`.

Comment: The line `iArray[x] = '\0';` will write to `iArray` out of bounds, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). For an array of size `4`, valid indexes are `0` to `3`, but you are using `0` to `4`.

Comment: In the line `iArray[x] = '\0';`, you appear to be confusing the null pointer constant (`NULL`) with the null character constant (`'\0'`). You should write `iArray[x] = NULL;` instead, assuming that `iArray` is supposed to be an array of pointers (of which I am not sure).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the way the loops are structured to receive and return info. Do you guys?

Comment: An assignment of zero (NULL) is falsey, so it stops of the first test.

Comment: The loop condition of the third loop `} while (iChoice != NULL);` should probably be `} while (iNumber != NULL);`, because `iChoice` does not change in that loop.

Answer (score 6):

Many issues (it is hard to say what OP had in mind writing it):

1. `*iArray = iNumber;` you assign pointer with the value of not initialized integer converted to pointer. Assignment makes no sense and also invokes undefined behaviour.
2. `iArray[x] = '\0';` where `x` is <0,4>. Same as above + accessing the array outside the bounds. Another UB
3. `printf("\nArray element #5: %d", iArray[4]);` you try to print pointer as integer (wrong format == UB all printfs) + access outside the bounds (UB)
4. `iChoice = NULL` you assign not compare. NULL is a special type of pointer.
5. ```
   do {
       printf("\n\t\tEnter a number to fill in: ");
       scanf("%d", &iNumber);
       break;
   } while (iChoice != NULL);
   ```

   break will terminate this loop after the scanf. The condition in `while` is not even reached.

*ALWAYS READ WARNINGS!!!!* Your code generates this bunch:

```
<source>:12:13: warning: assignment to 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   12 |     *iArray = iNumber;
      |             ^
<source>:21:38: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   21 |         printf("\nArray element #1: %d", iArray[0]);
      |                                     ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |         |
      |                                      int       int *
      |                                     %ls
<source>:22:38: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   22 |         printf("\nArray element #2: %d", iArray[1]);
      |                                     ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |         |
      |                                      int       int *
      |                                     %ls
<source>:23:38: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   23 |         printf("\nArray element #3: %d", iArray[2]);
      |                                     ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |         |
      |                                      int       int *
      |                                     %ls
<source>:24:38: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   24 |         printf("\nArray element #4: %d", iArray[3]);
      |                                     ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |         |
      |                                      int       int *
      |                                     %ls
<source>:25:38: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   25 |         printf("\nArray element #5: %d", iArray[4]);
      |                                     ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |         |
      |                                      int       int *
      |                                     %ls
<source>:28:22: warning: assignment to 'int' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   28 |     } while (iChoice = NULL);
      |                      ^
<source>:28:14: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   28 |     } while (iChoice = NULL);
      |              ^~~~~~~
<source>:34:22: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   34 |     } while (iChoice != NULL);
      |                      ^~
<source>:12:13: warning: 'iNumber' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   12 |     *iArray = iNumber;
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:9: note: 'iNumber' declared here
   11 |     int iNumber;
      |         ^~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: #4 - you mean "you assign NULL to ichoice"

Comment: @pm100 indeed but if we take into account the quality of the code - does it matter ? :)